# Integrating react into existing jQuery SPA

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, frontend

I currently have a single page app that was built in jQuery a few years ago. I want to slowly transition to react but I'm running into issues with building out sections at a time.

When calling reactDom.render() you have to pass in a parent "root" element that wraps the body of the site. I can't do this as it causes too many conflicts with existing JS and breaks the entire app.

Is there a way that I can target multiple sections of an app without a parent container?

For example

```
    <div id="main-page">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="search">load component here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="section">
                load component here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Load react into the `#search` and `#section` elements without a wrapping `reactDom.render(<component/>, document.getElementById('main-page')`.

What would be the best practice in this situation without re-writing the whole front-end?

Answer (score 0):

You delegate DOM operations to jQuery & React both. That's why there are so many conflicts.

So the best practice is to use one of the both.

Considering the actual situation, your app should be split into several parts. Every part is a sub-app and be managed by either jQuery or React, not both.

React allows you call `ReactDOM.render` many times in one web page. Every `ReactDOM.render` will run separately.